# Многотабличный SQL-запрос: вывод результатов в группе через запятую

Tags: sql

Здравствуйте, есть таблица в которой хранятся id-шники. Есть запрос который все эти id-шники заменяет на содержимое других таблиц. В общем что-то типа

```
SELECT
  t1_id,
  t2.t2_name AS t2_name,
  t3.t3_name AS t3.name
FROM
  t1
INNER JOIN
  t2 on t1.t2_id = t2.t2_id
INNER JOIN
  t3 on t3.t3_id = t3.t3_id
```

Если в какой-то из таблиц одному `t1_id` соответствует больше двух записей, то в результате запроса тоже выводится 2 записи для одного `id`.

Результат примерно такой:

```
t1_id t2_name t3_name
1      а        б
1      а        в
1      а        г
2      б        д
```

Вопрос такой: как можно записи сгруппировать по `t1_id`, чтобы получить

```
t1_id t2_name t3_name
1      а        б, в, г
2      б        д
```

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table

Comment: [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы убрать повторы, необходимо сгруппировать строки в результирующей таблице при помощи конструкции `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT
  t1_id,
  t2.t2_name AS t2_name,
  t3.t3_name AS t3.name
FROM
  t1
INNER JOIN
  t2 on t1.t2_id = t2.t2_id
INNER JOIN
  t3 on t3.t3_id = t3.t3_id
GROUP BY
  t1.id
```

Вторая часть задачи, получения значений в пределах группы через запятую зависит от конкретного диалекта SQL. Например, в MySQL эту задачу можно решить при помощи специальной агрегатной функции `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```
SELECT
  t1_id,
  t2.t2_name AS t2_name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(t3.t3_name) AS t3.name
FROM
  t1
INNER JOIN
  t2 on t1.t2_id = t2.t2_id
INNER JOIN
  t3 on t3.t3_id = t3.t3_id
GROUP BY
  t1.id
```